# The function in the loop is skipping for the first time when value is being "entered by user" otherwise working fine..why?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class holes{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String onec="ADOPQR";
            String twoc="B";
            int testcases=0;
            Scanner userinput=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the number of testcases");
            testcases=userinput.nextInt();
            int ones=0;
            int twos=0;
            String[] list=new String[testcases];
            for(int i=0; i<testcases; i++){
                String temp;
                System.out.print("Now enter the string " + (i+1));
                temp=userinput.nextLine();
                list[i]=temp;
            }

            for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<list[i].length(); j++){
                    for(int k=0; k<twoc.length(); k++){
                        if(list[i].charAt(j) == onec.charAt(k))
                            ones++;
                        else if(list[i].charAt(j) == twoc.charAt(0))
                        {
                            twos++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else;


                    }

                }
                System.out.println(ones + "  " + twos);
                ones=twos=0;
            }

            userinput.close();

        }

    }
```

> this is the solution of the question 
>   oles in the text 
>   Problem code: HOLES
>   SUBMITALL SUBMISSIONS
>   All submissions for this problem are available.

Chef wrote some text on a piece of paper and now he wants to know how many holes are in the text. What is a hole? If you think of the paper as the plane and a letter as a curve on the plane, then each letter divides the plane into regions. For example letters "A", "D", "O", "P", "R" divide the plane into two regions so we say these letters each have one hole. Similarly, letter "B" has two holes and letters such as "C", "E", "F", "K" have no holes. We say that the number of holes in the text is equal to the total number of holes in the letters of the text. Help Chef to determine how many holes are in the text.
Input

The first line contains a single integer T <= 40, the number of test cases. T test cases follow. The only line of each test case contains a non-empty text composed only of uppercase letters of English alphabet. The length of the text is less then 100. There are no any spaces in the input.
Output

For each test case, output a single line containing the number of holes in the corresponding text.
Example

Input:
2
CODECHEF
DRINKEATCODE

Output:
2
5

Comment: It's unclear what is actually going wrong. Please give more details of what you ran, what you entered, what you saw, what you expected. Otherwise we're just guessing

Answer (score 1):

Just after `testcases=userinput.nextInt();` add a line like:

```
 userinput.nextLine();
```

nextInt api won't consume return key (which you pressed when entering number) and hence you will need to consume it with nextLine method.